# DocumentDB - How to get request charge within stored procedure?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I must be missing something or searching the wrong way but i can't seem to find any source/example of how to get request charge of particular query within stored procedure.

So, lets say i have just 3 ordinary read sql queries within stored procedure and i want to console.log (to Azure portal console) request charge for each.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not available today with Azure Cosmos DB. The ['x-ms-request-charge'] value will be in the range of the RUs consumed by the individual operations performed outside the stored procedure.

Comment: Any update and/or tracking link for this as feature request?