# How can I get the number of RU's consumed when executing a stored procedure in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am writing a Cosmos DB stored procedure which has multiple Queries inside it. I want to know the number of RU's consumed when the Stored Procedure Executes.Once the Stored Procedure is executed there is no log of number of RU's consumed,which appears when Query is executed.

Is there any method by which I can view the RU's consumed for executing the Stored Procedure ?

Comment: How do you execute the stored procedure? Are you using the .NET SDK?

Comment: I am currently executing the stored procedures through portal any way to get it through the portal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know,If you want get `RUs` of `executeStoredProcedure` method in Cosmos DB SDK, please use `getRequestCharge()` method. It won't show in the portal.

Such as code:

```
StoredProcedureResponse resourceResponse = documentClient.executeStoredProcedure("dbs/db/colls/item/sprocs/b",requestOptions ,null);
System.out.println(resourceResponse.getRequestCharge());
```

If you want to get request charge of internal SQL in stored procedure.It can't be done so far.You could see this [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014707/documentdb-how-to-get-request-charge-within-stored-procedure).

> This is not available today with Azure Cosmos DB. The
>   ['x-ms-request-charge'] value will be in the range of the RUs consumed
>   by the individual operations performed outside the stored procedure.

If you do concern this feature, you could submit [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) here to trace the progress.

Hope it helps you.