# CosmosDB Stored Proc heuristic for document size from readDocument

Tags: javascript, json, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I have a [stored proc that reads and updates a document](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/c0a60824aae47f38aaec4d676622c24dc5a7ed2e/src/Equinox.Cosmos/Cosmos.fs#L318). As part of this processing, I'd like to be able to react to the cost of the read (in RU, or a proxy for it like counting JSON size; it doesn't have to be precise) in order that I can have the logic archive information out to an adjacent document when reaching a threshold.

Is there a clean way to obtain the approximate RU cost of a `readDocument` I've just performed within a stored proc?

Comment: older, less specific arguably duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014707. (If answer involves `jsonify`...`length` whats the rough perf or RU impact in CosmosDB?)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get the RU charge from inside a stored procedure as this is calculated outside of it's execution and sent in the response object back to the SDK client. There is also no good way of estimating it. The length of the serialized string is not a good means as RU charge for reads relies heavily on the indexing policy in place on the container.

Comment: Thanks Mark - Doesn't the fact I'm doing a doing a point read of the entire document (`readDocument`) not reduce the variability of the cost somewhat? essentially if I used `jsonify` and applied the per-KB (non-linear) cost function, I'd have a good proxy ? To restate the question: is there any way within the readDocument continuation to obtain any details _of any kind_ regarding the preceding call ? (To reduce the xy problem further: I'm feeding events into a stored proc pretty much blind, and am seeking to limit the document sizes I produce by proactively splitting when I hit a threshold)

Comment: Point read for 1K or less of data is always 1 RU. I don't know what the cost of a point read is for data over 1KB but you could measure this and for point read operations this should remain consistent.

Comment: Yes; but my question is: if I call `readDocument` within a stored proc, is there any way to determine the size of the document (or the charge) I've read in the continuation programmatically (see code to stored proc I linked if it helps...)